# I can't make an image to fill a whole column div

Tags: html, css

I inserted an image in a `div class="col-md"` but as you can see from the photo the image cannot fill the whole column div and leaves some edges not covered. how can I do?

HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md" style="border: 2px solid blue">
            <img id="imm" src="dog.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <h1 style="color:crimson">dog</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
#imm{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure your image doesn't have white border horizontal

Comment: `col-md` likely has some padding value.

Comment: @YvesKipondo 
no because I tried also with other images and nothing changes

Comment: @BenM It happen too if I use only col

Comment: @nikpote _It happen too if I use only col_ I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap. `col` elements have a padding of `15px` on the left and right.

Comment: @disinfor yes i'm using bootstrap, so to delete the padding of 15px what can I do? Just dont use bootstrap?

Comment: You can use bootstrap. Bootstrap has utility class to remove padding if you want, add `pl-md-0` and `pr-md-0` to your `col-md` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/ Answer below.

Comment: if you add the class `p-0` to the `col-md` holding the image, it's plenty enough to start from ;) link to bootstrap already given ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has utility class to remove padding if you want, add `pl-md-0` and `pr-md-0` to your `col-md`

`pr-md-0` basically means: padding right on medium screens set it to 0. `pl-xx-x` means padding left.

```css
#imm{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md pl-md-0 pr-md-0" style="border: 2px solid blue">
            <img id="imm" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <h1 style="color:crimson">dog</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `col-md-*` classes adds some padding horizontally. In Bootstrap v4, there's a class called [no-gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters) which you can add to the `row` element to remove the padding.

Here's the example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md" style="border: 2px solid blue">
            <img id="imm" src="https://picsum.photos/1000">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <h1 style="color:crimson">dog</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n13zucg/

Comment: p-0 on the img container is also enough and avoids ressetting padding everywhere else ;) https://jsfiddle.net/Lnrdg3jo/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Ah! I missed that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

use this syntax in image class

```
.image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover; 
}
```

or object-fit:fill;